# Can I access a onion site which is being hosted behind a LAN?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have a quick question I hope has not been asked yet.

I am using Windows 10 and I don't have any router, a ethernet cable is being directly connected to my computer. I don't have any static IP not even IPv6. And basically my computer is in my ISP's local are network (LAN) because I saw in my adapter properties that I have have a address like `10.72.99.17` which is of course a private IP and when I type the gateway address my ISP login page opens.

And yes I want to tell you one more thing that when I was surfing some onion sites, I opened the dev tools and went to the network tab and saw IP address of these sites, it was `0.0.0.0`. This boosted my curiosity a 100 times.

But this created a confusion in my mind that if tor is just a private network in the Internet, does it matter that a onion site  is being hosted behind a LAN or not.

Can someone access my onion site which is being hosted in a LAN, from outside that LAN

Answer (score 1):

> does it matter that a onion site is being hosted behind a LAN or not.
>
> Can someone access my onion site which is being hosted in a LAN, from
>   outside that LAN

Yes, they can access it without a problem. The tor service on your computer reaches out to the Tor network and starts the connection. When someone visits your website, the Tor network knows how to reach the onion service that you are hosting via that connection. If you stop your web server or you stop the tor service, then they can't reach it anymore. If you want an in-depth explanation, then read the [Tor design document](https://svn-archive.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.html) and other [documentation](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/documentation.html.en#DesignDoc).